# Mysql -- Need something like UPDATE [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY [...]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, on-duplicate-key

I'm validating the e-mails of several databases.
Our validation provider created us a list of e-mails with a status to put (checked, non-responding, and so on...)

But for some adresses, we also got a fix (e.g.  foo@gail.com => foo@g**m**ail.com)

I need to put the right status (20), and only sometimes fix the e-mail.  I also could have to fix the mail while the status is already right.

My current PDO request to update those is as follows :

```
$req_fix_mail_and_update_status = "
    UPDATE {$user_table_name}
        SET status = :mail_status1
        , {$mail_column_name} = :mail_fixed1
    WHERE (({$mail_column_name} LIKE :mail_address)  OR  ({$mail_column_name} LIKE :mail_fixed2))
        AND ((status != :mail_status2) OR ({$mail_column_name} NOT LIKE :mail_fixed3))
";
```

Now, here comes the tricky part :

One of the databases stores data about several websites, and **may** contain mail duplicates.

I got a composed unique constraint on something like `(fk_site, email)`

... and an edge case, with some e-mails having both "fixed" and "non-fixed" values entries

e.g. :

```
Login   FK_Site  Mail            Status
Alice        01  foo@gmail.com        0
Alice        01  foo@gmal.com         0
Bob          02  foo@gmal.com         0
```

Of course, trying to fix the wrong adress would makes duplicate invalid because of the (fk_site, email) unique constraint would fail on Alice => the requests fails (#$%§@&!).

But Bob stil needs his mail fixed, and the lines need their status updated, too !

I'm looking for a way to get around this, but can't find anything with SQL.
Making one (say, up to two) more requests when I fail could be ok, but it seems to be a slippy way, and I don't want to turn the task to something dirty and unreadable for such an edge cas

Typically, an `UPDATE [...] with a "ON DUPLICATE KEY <just update status>"` clause is what I'd need, but I wasn't surprise to see is doesn't exist.

*My worker is written in PHP, and uses PDO*

Any idea ?

Comment: I would just catch the exception, see whether it's on the duplicate key, and then just fire an update query.

Comment: @Your Common Sense
I thought of that, but if I consider my example case, I don't only have to execute a new request for the status, I also need to update Bob's wrong e-mail without trying to update Alice's.
The 2nd update would need to fix *only* the lines which don't have an equivalent for the other values provoking the constraint violation.

I tried using a subselect, but it didn't seem possible to me with an update.  Maybe with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause ?  I'll dig that again.

Comment: wait, with your source data you don't have the site id?

Comment: @Your Common Sense Sure I do, but I don't know how to exploit it in my request.

I just tested the following, but it fails with "Can't specify target table p1 in from clause".

`UPDATE prospect p1
SET firstname='UPDATED', status = 20
WHERE 
    email="<wrong_value>"
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT id FROM prospect p2
        WHERE 
            email = "<right_value>"
            AND p1.site_id = p2.site_id
            AND p1.origin = p2.origin
    )`
*Note that I got a 3rd column in my unique constraint*

Comment: Looks like I found a way, using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in conjunction with a subselect.
`UPDATE prospect p1
SET email="<fixed_value>", status = 20

WHERE 
    p1.email="<wrong_value>"
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM prospect cpy) as p2
        WHERE 
            email = "<fixed_value>"
            AND p1.site_id = p2.site_id
            AND p1.origin = p2.origin
        )`

I got some doubts about the performances, but since few lines will be concerned, it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: Its not without drawbacks, but works.  I'll make a detailed answer of what I did... and what I couldn't, when I'm back.  Btw, feel free to propose better solutions if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the substitute "answer" to my problem.
Note that a more simple solution (if it exists...) would be welcome.

It technically solves my needs, but is pretty ugly and costs me 3 extra requests instead of one.

- One to update the mail & status of lines having a wrong mail which wont create a duplicate once mail is fixed
- One to update only the status of lines having an already correct e-mail
- One to update only the status of lines having a mail which cant be fixed due to the constraint

This is a bit heavy, but performance isn't an issue here.  What bugs me is that it makes the code less readable, and a detailed explanation is needed to understand WHY 3 requests are necessary.

Here's my (PDO) request to update only lines which wouldn't create a duplicate :

```
UPDATE prospect p1
    SET email = :mail_fixed1
    ,status = :mail_status1
WHERE 
    p1.email = :mail_address
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT site_id FROM (SELECT site_id, email, origin  FROM  prospect cpy) as p2
        WHERE 
            email = :mail_fixed2
            AND p1.site_id = p2.site_id
            AND p1.origin = p2.origin
        )
```

- The unicity constraint is on the triplet (**`site_id, email, origin`**)
- Placeholders like `:mail_fixed1` and `:mail_fixed2` have the same values bound.  The reason why I have to use different ones is because my script also connects to a SQL-Server database, and the driver crashes with an unintelligible error when a placeholder is used more than once.
- My 3nd request, which only updates lines for which the mail fix WOULD create a duplicate is the same, except "NOT EXISTS" is replaced with "EXISTS" (*also, the mail isn't modified, and the status is fixed, but those are details*)

---

The 2rd request in-between has nothing particular, but I put it here for completeness sake :

```
UPDATE {$user_table_name}
    SET status = :mail_status1
WHERE ({$mail_column_name} LIKE :mail_address)
    AND ((status IS NULL)  OR  (status != :mail_status2))
```

I forgot to mention one other little drawback : my script used to count the precise number of updated lines, but it may now count a few lines more than once, since the same line can be updated by 2 requests.  It's a small detail, but remains annoying.

Anyway, I hope this post will help someone else !